# SQL Injection - if we concatenate multiple pre-defined strings with a user value

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sql-injection, code-injection

If I create a DB based on concatenation of strings but with some pre-defined values, then is my DB susceptible to SQL injections?

For example: In the below example I have provided with a pre-defined drop-down menu from which users will select values and that will be extracted into strings and then all strings will be concatenated for *table name*(in this case it is *course*. This was done to make tables at run time based on the requirement.

I am creating a simple java project, but irrespective of the language, in this scenario is SQL injection possible?

Sorry, if this is a lame question, but would like to know the scenario for a future case.

```
                String department = jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString();
                String year = jComboBox2.getSelectedItem().toString();
                String batch = jComboBox3.getSelectedItem().toString();
                String subject = jTextField1.getText();
                String assigned = jComboBox4.getSelectedItem().toString();
                String course = department+"_"+year+"_"+batch+"_"+subject;                
                Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
                con = DriverManager.getConnection("pathToDB");
                pst = con.prepareStatement("insert into courses(course,department,subject,teacher_assigned) values (?,?,?,?)");
                pst.setString(1,course);
                pst.setString(2,department);
                pst.setString(3,subject);
                pst.setString(4,assigned);
                int result = pst.executeUpdate();
                if(result==1){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Courses has been added, please ask teacher to assign themselves.");
                }
                else{
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Some issue with connection"); 
                }
                jTextField1.setText("");
                String strQuery="CREATE TABLE $table_name"+ "("+ " id int primary key AUTO_INCREMENT, attenndancedate Date, rollno int);";
                String query =strQuery.replace("$table_name",course);
                pst1 = con.prepareStatement(query);
                boolean resultcreate = pst1.execute();
                if(resultcreate){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Create table worked, hooray!!!");
                }
                else{
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Some issue with connection for create table"); 
                }
```

Comment: Using PreparedStatement should be a habit. It's faster and safer.

Comment: @Spectric Is there any other way to make dynamic tables at run time and also to avoid SQL injection?

Comment: Creating tables at user's request is a very bad practice on its own. Learn the relational database architecture and have a single predefined table for all the data. Problem solved

Comment: @YourCommonSense I am not asking/telling user to create a table. Its just that- based on certain entries of the user, I want to create a table. Now, this might be a bad practice for others but for me it looks like "more dynamic". So, instead of accepting it as a bad practice, I am trying to find a workaround of this bad practice. I am a newbie so trying to learn. :-D

Answer (score 0):

Your code is prone to SQL Injection. If a user enters something like this in `subject`:

`sometable (id int primary key); --`

Then your table definition `id int primary key AUTO_INCREMENT, attenndancedate Date, rollno int` will be overwritten with `(id int primary key)`.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be answering the question asked.  "maybe using third party libraries" hardly counts as one

Comment: The question OP asked was "in this scenario is SQL injection possible?", I suggested an example with SQL Injection. Though recommendation about third-party libs was not good, agree with you.

Comment: Hi @nkrivenko it is said that if we use prepared statement, we can prevent our code from SQL Injection. Now I am taking the input by user and then trying to add it to some string values and then use it to create table....Is my code still susceptible to SQL Injection?